# C# catch exception being ignored thus application crushes

Tags: c#, try-catch, registry

I need to make an application in WinForm C# as my final programming project. The project is about managing Registry more nicely to make it easier for the user to edit values.

The problem is, when I read whether the *UninstallString* exists or not, the function for some reason doesn't look in the catch inside the try when it fails (and it fails since the app isn't 64-bit, thus the Registry value needs to be accessed differently)

```
public bool ValueExists(string Key, string Value)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(Key);
                return rk.GetValue(Value) != null; //Error happens here when selected 64-bit application. System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                RegistryKey regkey64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
                RegistryKey rk64 = regkey64.OpenSubKey(Value);
                return regkey64.OpenSubKey(Key).GetValue(Value) != null;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' - This is the error and I KNOW it happens cause I select a 64-bit application, but for some reason it ignores the catch.

Comment: Get a stack trace where this happens

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line. Is `rk` null? If so, why and handle it.

Comment: It’s unreadable since it’s a 64-bit Registry Value (meaning, if I select a 32-bit application this exception won’t happen), thus I made this exception. What more can I do to handle it?

Comment: so is `rk` null?

Comment: How did you set your application 64-bit? Could you show code/project? Are you sure that `rk` is null (using debugger)?

Comment: There is no reason to catch NullReferenceException anyway, when you can just check if target variable is null with "if"

Comment: @Evk I can’t check it with if cause it will crash when I’ll try to read a selected 64-bot Registry value

Comment: @Hostel The try inside the try can read selected 32-bit Registry values, but when 64-bit Registry value is selected it crashes with the error I wrote the as a comment. Thus I wrote the catch inside the try, to read 64-bit Registry selected values, but for some reason it ignores it. So if I select a 32-bit Registry value it goes to check whether the value exists or not, if not it's null and it return false, if exists it's not null and it return true.

Comment: @Jonathan rk is null under the right circumstances - which means it the selected 32-bit Registry value doesn't exists. But again, if the selected Registry value is 64-bit it'd be unreadable for the code in the try inside the try, and I'll need to use the code in the try inside the catch (to check whether a 64-bit Registry value exists or not).

Comment: In your try block, you're not checking if `rk` is null or not before you order it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User named **Richard Deeming** solved the problem for me in [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5284472/Csharp-catch-exception-being-ignored-thus-applicat)

He suggested a whole different approach. Instead of using catch, he checks if the proccess is 64-bit and this way he directs the code whether to force 64-bit Registry value reading or not (depends on the selected program). This is his code (with a fix I made):

```
public bool ValueExists(string Key, string Value)
    {
        using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(Key, false))
        {
            if (rk != null) return rk.GetValue(Value) != null;
        }

        if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
        {
            RegistryKey regkey64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
            return regkey64.OpenSubKey(Key).GetValue(Value) != null;
        }

        return false;
    }
```